# Sethna 3.2.1 - What does it mean to integrate over configuration space?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, notation, volume

I'm having trouble understanding the examples Sethna uses in this section to illustrate the microcanonical ensemble.

First he talks about the probability density $\rho(Q)$ that $N$ ideal gas particles will be in position space configuration $Q\in R^{3N}$ inside a box of volume $V$. He says that since $\int \rho dQ=1$ and integrating over the positions gives a factor of $V$ for each of the $N$ particles, $\rho (Q)=1/V^N$.

I am confused by a few things here. First, what does it mean to integrate over position space, and where does the factor of $V$ come from for each position? This is confusing to me because $Q$ is a position vector and the volume is continuous, so why can we give any answer besides there are an infinite number of spatial configurations? Second, what is $R^{3N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spatial microscopic configuration of a set of $N$ non-interacting point-like particles in 3D is given once we have all the positions, i.e. the set of all the position vectors $Q=\{{\bf r}_1, \dots , {\bf r}_N  \}$.

If the particles are confined in a finite volume, each cartesian component of the position ${\bf r}_i$ is an element of a subset of the real numbers $R$, each position vector  ${\bf r}_i$ is inside a finite volume $V$, and the $3N$ position $Q$ is an element of a finite volume subset of $R^{3N}$, the $3N$-fold cartesian product of $R$,  of volume $V^{N}$.

Notice that the continuity of the values of the positions has nothing to do with the spatial dimensionality. When we say that the continuous values of the position ${\bf r}_i$ belong to a 3D space, we mean that we need $3$ real numbers to uniquely assign a position in the space.

Comment: So the position space has 3N dimensions. But why is the volume of the subspace V^{3N}? Shouldn’t it be V^N since V is 3D? Also, while your point about the continuity is well taken, why does that make the probability distribution nonzero? In 3D space each particle could be anywhere!

Comment: It was my mistake. Of course, the volume in the $3N$ dimensional space is $V^N$.

Comment: @idiot-physicist For continuous probability distributions, the probability of finding a point in a volume $dV$ is $\rho({\bf r}) dV$. In the case of a uniform distribution it is $\frac{dV}{V} $. Therefore it is zero for a single point ($dV=0$) but different from zero for any finite subvolume.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying. I was a little confused because our expression for the probability density doesn't depend on Q (but that is how it should be, because the probability distribution is constant). What would it look like for us to integrate this expression from Q to Q+dQ? After all, Q is a vector.